# aliases not working while using Storybook/vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, storybook

I'm using [Storybook](https://storybook.js.org/) for Vue and I'm trying to add aliases to the webpack config in `storybook/main.js`:

```
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
      '@': path.resolve('src'),
        '@': 'src',
      '@src': 'src'
    },
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.vue', '.json']
  },
```

This is how my file structure looks:

[image]

And the error I'm getting:

```
npm run storybook
    > scss-loader-example@0.1.0 storybook /Users/test/Documents/webdev/test/scss-loader-example
    > start-storybook -p 6006

    info @storybook/vue v5.3.17
    info
    info => Loading presets
    info => Loading presets
    info => Adding stories defined in ".storybook/main.js".
    info => Using default Webpack setup.
    webpack built c29ceda255d3976f13b9 in 9398ms
    ✖ ｢wdm｣: Hash: c29ceda255d3976f13b9
    Version: webpack 4.42.0
    Time: 9398ms
    Built at: 2020-03-18 11:41:13
                                              Asset      Size        Chunks                                Chunk Names
                                        iframe.html  2.87 KiB                [emitted]
                main.c29ceda255d3976f13b9.bundle.js   321 KiB          main  [emitted] [immutable]  [big]  main
            main.c29ceda255d3976f13b9.bundle.js.map   213 KiB          main  [emitted] [dev]               main
        runtime~main.c29ceda255d3976f13b9.bundle.js  31.2 KiB  runtime~main  [emitted] [immutable]         runtime~main
    runtime~main.c29ceda255d3976f13b9.bundle.js.map  32.3 KiB  runtime~main  [emitted] [dev]               runtime~main
        vendors~main.c29ceda255d3976f13b9.bundle.js  2.68 MiB  vendors~main  [emitted] [immutable]  [big]  vendors~main
    vendors~main.c29ceda255d3976f13b9.bundle.js.map  2.79 MiB  vendors~main  [emitted] [dev]               vendors~main
    Entrypoint main [big] = runtime~main.c29ceda255d3976f13b9.bundle.js runtime~main.c29ceda255d3976f13b9.bundle.js.map vendors~main.c29ceda255d3976f13b9.bundle.js vendors~main.c29ceda255d3976f13b9.bundle.js.map main.c29ceda255d3976f13b9.bundle.js main.c29ceda255d3976f13b9.bundle.js.map
    [0] multi ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/common/polyfills.js ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/preview/globals.js ./.storybook/generated-entry.js (webpack)-hot-middleware/client.js?reload=true&quiet=true 64 bytes {main} [built]
    [./.storybook/generated-entry.js] 230 bytes {main} [built]
    [./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/common/polyfills.js] 120 bytes {vendors~main} [built]
    [./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/preview/globals.js] 93 bytes {vendors~main} [built]
    [./node_modules/@storybook/vue/dist/client/index.js] 1.21 KiB {vendors~main} [built]
    [./node_modules/airbnb-js-shims/index.js] 40 bytes {vendors~main} [built]
    [./node_modules/core-js/features/symbol/index.js] 359 bytes {vendors~main} [built]
    [./node_modules/global/window.js] 232 bytes {vendors~main} [built]
    [./node_modules/querystring-es3/index.js] 127 bytes {vendors~main} [built]
    [./node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js] 23.6 KiB {vendors~main} [built]
    [./node_modules/webpack-hot-middleware/client-overlay.js] (webpack)-hot-middleware/client-overlay.js 2.17 KiB {vendors~main} [built]
    [./node_modules/webpack-hot-middleware/client.js?reload=true&quiet=true] (webpack)-hot-middleware/client.js?reload=true&quiet=true 7.68 KiB {vendors~main} [built]
    [./node_modules/webpack-hot-middleware/node_modules/strip-ansi/index.js] (webpack)-hot-middleware/node_modules/strip-ansi/index.js 161 bytes {vendors~main} [built]
    [./node_modules/webpack-hot-middleware/process-update.js] (webpack)-hot-middleware/process-update.js 4.35 KiB {vendors~main} [built]
    [./node_modules/webpack/buildin/harmony-module.js] (webpack)/buildin/harmony-module.js 573 bytes {vendors~main} [built]
        + 708 hidden modules

    ERROR in ./src/components/Balance.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (./node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/Balance.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&)
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@/js/automation-const' in '/Users/test/Documents/webdev/test/scss-loader-example/src/components'
     @ ./src/components/Balance.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (./node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/Balance.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&) 27:0-56 53:13-32
     @ ./src/components/Balance.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
     @ ./src/components/Balance.vue
     @ ./stories/1-Button.stories.js
     @ ./stories sync ^\.\/(?:(?:(?!\.)(?:(?:(?!(?:|\/)\.).)*?)\/)?(?!\.)(?=.)[^\/]*?\.stories\.js\/?)$
     @ ./.storybook/generated-entry.js
     @ multi ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/common/polyfills.js ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/preview/globals.js ./.storybook/generated-entry.js (webpack)-hot-middleware/client.js?reload=true&quiet=true

    ERROR in ./src/components/Balance.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (./node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/Balance.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&)
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@/js/utils/helper' in '/Users/test/Documents/webdev/test/scss-loader-example/src/components'
     @ ./src/components/Balance.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (./node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/Balance.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&) 26:0-39 57:19-25
     @ ./src/components/Balance.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
     @ ./src/components/Balance.vue
     @ ./stories/1-Button.stories.js
     @ ./stories sync ^\.\/(?:(?:(?!\.)(?:(?:(?!(?:|\/)\.).)*?)\/)?(?!\.)(?=.)[^\/]*?\.stories\.js\/?)$
     @ ./.storybook/generated-entry.js
     @ multi ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/common/polyfills.js ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/preview/globals.js ./.storybook/generated-entry.js (webpack)-hot-middleware/client.js?reload=true&quiet=true
    Child HtmlWebpackCompiler:
                              Asset     Size               Chunks  Chunk Names
        __child-HtmlWebpackPlugin_0  6.5 KiB  HtmlWebpackPlugin_0  HtmlWebpackPlugin_0
        Entrypoint HtmlWebpackPlugin_0 = __child-HtmlWebpackPlugin_0
        [./node_modules/@storybook/core/node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/templates/index.ejs] 2.15 KiB {HtmlWebpackPlugin_0} [built]

    WARN Broken build, fix the error above.
    WARN You may need to refresh the browser.
```

And the paths inside `Balance.vue` which are causing the issue:

```
import helper from '@/js/utils/helper'
import automationConstants from '@/js/automation-const'
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: *Using default Webpack setup* - that's the problem. Where are exactly webpack config entries located in main.js? Docs clearly say they should be in webpackFinal, https://storybook.js.org/docs/configurations/custom-webpack-config/

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I'm considering not using the `@` alias, which would be a shame.

Answer (score 0):

I created a separate `webpack.config.js` file in my `.storybook` folder and used the following config.

```js
config.resolve.alias = {
    ...config.resolve.alias,
    '@': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/'),
    vue$: 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
};
```

make sure to also add `vue$` otherwise the vue compiler will be broken.